# unpacking the tar file after installing oozie on linux

Tags: oozie

I am trying to install oozie on my linux system. I have installed using following command

```
curl -O http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/incubator/oozie/oozie-3.1.3-incubating/oozie-3.1.3-incubating-distro.tar.gz
```

I can see the file on my local system. The problem comes when unpacking the tar using the statement

```
tar –xzvf <PATH_TO_OOZIE_TAR> I get following error

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have used the following command to see what type of file it is a html document. How can I unpack the tar file? I am following the steps from `https://vdocuments.site/oozie-hug-may12.html`

file oozie-3.1.3-incubating-distro.tar.gz

I get `oozie-3.1.3-incubating-distro.tar.gz: HTML document text`

Answer (score 1):

@user2708013 the link you are using is a very old incubating version of Oozie.  As such it appears to be invalid.

Lets try a new version:

```
 wget https://downloads.apache.org/oozie/5.2.0/oozie-5.2.0.tar.gz
 tar xzvf oozie-5.2.0.tar.gz
```